# julia DataFrame select over multiple DateTime ranges

Tags: julia

How does one select multiple datetime ranges from a DataFrame?

```
ranges = [(start=DateTime(0),stop=DateTime(10)), (start=DateTime(50),stop=DateTime(70))]

dt_ranges = map(oh -> (df.datetime .>= oh.start) .& (df.datetime .<= oh.stop), ranges)

df[dt_ranges, j]
```

This doesn't select the ranges. It errors out with ArgError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this this way:

```
julia> ranges = [(start=DateTime(0),stop=DateTime(10)), (start=DateTime(50),stop=DateTime(70))]
2-element Vector{NamedTuple{(:start, :stop), Tuple{DateTime, DateTime}}}:
 (start = DateTime("0000-01-01T00:00:00"), stop = DateTime("0010-01-01T00:00:00"))
 (start = DateTime("0050-01-01T00:00:00"), stop = DateTime("0070-01-01T00:00:00"))

julia> inrange(ranges) = moment -> any(x -> x.start <= moment <= x.stop, ranges)
inrange (generic function with 1 method)

julia> df = DataFrame(moments = [DateTime(-1), DateTime(5), DateTime(20), DateTime(60), DateTime(80)])
5×1 DataFrame
 Row │ moments
     │ DateTime
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ -0001-01-01T00:00:00
   2 │ 0005-01-01T00:00:00
   3 │ 0020-01-01T00:00:00
   4 │ 0060-01-01T00:00:00
   5 │ 0080-01-01T00:00:00

julia> filter(:moments => inrange(ranges), df)
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ moments
     │ DateTime
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │ 0005-01-01T00:00:00
   2 │ 0060-01-01T00:00:00
```

(if something is unclear please comment; note that `inrange` is a higher-order function returning a function that takes a time moment to check)